# Java application not reading environment variables from .env file

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables, slack-api, ngrok

I am creating a Slack bot using Bolt framework in Java + Maven following [this](https://slack.dev/java-slack-sdk/guides/getting-started-with-bolt) tutorial on their official website. My bot requires some keys that should be present as environment variables.

The application works just fine when I export those variables in the terminal prior to executing the application like this.

```bash
export SLACK_BOT_TOKEN=xoxb-...your-own-valid-one
export SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET=123abc...your-own-valid-one

mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="hello.MyApp"
```

But when I don't, and instead save them in a `.env` file, the `App` constructor apparently doesn't get those keys even though I have loaded them in the main method from `.env` file.

Here is my main method:

```java
package hello;
import com.slack.api.bolt.App;
import com.slack.api.bolt.jetty.SlackAppServer;
import io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.Dotenv;

public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Dotenv dotenv = Dotenv.configure().directory("./").load();
        System.out.println(dotenv.get("SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"));
        System.out.println(dotenv.get("SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET"));

//         CREATING THE SLACK APP
        App slackApp = new App();
        slackApp.command("/mytesthello", (req, ctx)-> {
            return ctx.ack(":wave: Hello!");
        });

        SlackAppServer slackAppServer = new SlackAppServer(slackApp);
        slackAppServer.start();
    }
}
```

The console is able to show the correct output using `System.out.println` indicating that the variables are accessible, but most probably the `App()` constructor is not able to get them, since whenever I try to make POST request from my slack app, the `ngrok` interface as well as my terminal show `unauthorized access`. (again, this is the case when I don't export the environment variables)

What should I do to make sure that the environment variables are available from `.env` file? Otherwise it would be very cumbersome to keep exporting them whenever I run the application.

Comment: Those environment variables haven't been loaded into the _system_, they have been loaded into the created `dotenv`.  Have you tried adding `Dotenv...systemProperties().load();` to load them and make them available via `System.getProperty` (as that's more likely where the `App` instance looks for them).

Comment: @BeUndead I tried this, but still the terminal shows `invalid signature` and ngrok logs show `unauthorized access`